# SSL MITM and java applet

Tags: ssl, applet

I'm currently working on a project which involves building a digital fortress on the client side(Browser) to mitigate against Man-in-the-middle attacks on SSL's PKI infrastructure. Though they're numerous possibilities of mounting man-in-the-middle attacks on SSL connections but I'm meant to focus on the issues with the PKI infrastructure and also taking the system's performance into consideration.

After doing a wee bit of research these are the following task I think I'm set out to achieve

1. Ascertaining the validity period of a certificate by checking its validity period and checking if a certificate's serial number exists in a CRL list
2. Disabling MD5 for certificate checking
3. Ensuring the server the client(Browser) is connecting to is the real server. Can this be achieved by a URL or by simply by doing a DNS lookup?, because I think both URL and DNS are not also secured to some extent. I'm thinking of this web server fingerprinting thing but yet I still need a repository to check with.What else can i use??
4. Certificate Fingerprint. Are they any certificate hash or fingerprint repository that are trusted that I can lookup the fingerprints of certificate??.

What else do I need to check to stop man-in-the-middle attacks??

I intend to use a java Applet embedded in a browser to handle this task and so I know it is impossible to connect to a web server without the website's login page. The issue is how can I make a test connection to the server using my Applet embedded page just to get the server's certificate or better still is it possible to do a connection using the website's login page and terminating the SSL handshake after the server sends a certificate so the Applet just go into the certificate store to retrieve the certificate and analyze the certificate to safeguard against Man-in-the-middle attack.

As I've said I would like to use java build the solution because it is widely speculated that java applet are more faster than javascripts. And also browser extensions are mostly platform dependent which is not in the case of java Applets. Can this be a performance yardstick??

Answer (score -1):

> Ascertaining the validity period of a certificate by checking its validity period and checking if a certificate's serial number exists in a CRL list

The browser already does that.

> Disabling MD5 for certificate checking

Why? If the certificate has an MD5 hash you must check it. How does removing that mitigate MITM attacks! This doesn't make sense.

> Ensuring the server the client(Browser) is connecting to is the real server.

The browser already does that. It's built into the HTTPS protocol.

> Can this be achieved by a URL or by simply by doing a DNS lookup?, because i think both URL and DNS are not also secured to some extent.

No, no, no, and no.

> I'm thinking of this web server fingerprinting thing but yet i still need a repository to check with. What else can i use?

What you're asking doesn't make sense in the first place.

> Certificate Fingerprint. Are they any certificate hash or fingerprint repository that are trusted that i can lookup the fingerprints of certificate?.

Err, the MD5 hash if any that you're so busy trying to bypass and the digital signature already accomplish that.

The suggestion to use an applet inside the browser to protect the browser doesn't make sense either. I think you've been handed a non-problem, a lot of contradictory and in some cases meaningless requirements, and a lot of bad advice as to how to implement it.

Comment: Why? If the certificate has an MD5 hash you must check it. How does removing that mitigate MITM attacks! This doesn't make sense.

Collision Attacks on MD5 allow the attacker to produce the exact same hashvalue, which they can later attach to a certificate with a different domain name. In other words, the attacker can impersonate a root CA and start issuing certificates. I only want SHA2 enabled for certificate checking.

Comment: The browser already does that. It's built into the HTTPS protocol.

If this is correct, then why are SSL phising attacks possible. If i can fool a user to click on a URL that looks like "barclay.co.uk" instead of "barclays.co.uk" then i've breached the system because the user will be thinking he's actually cnnecting to the server so the need to know the server you're connecting to vital. It is a known fact that DNS and URL are not trustworthy to ascertain the identity of a server thats the reason i'm thinking of fingerprinting the web server to create a unique identity for it.

Comment: The suggestion to use an applet inside the browser to protect the browser doesn't make sense either. I think you've been handed a non-problem, a lot of contradictory and in some cases meaningless requirements, and a lot of bad advice as to how to implement it.


The applet is not going to protect the browser, it is going to check all these listed tasks on receiving a certificate. I'm trying to use an Apllet because of performance. So, i'm asking if using applet is a good solution and is it faster than using extensions.

Comment: (1) You don't need to quote what I've already said. (2) SSL phishing attacks are possible because the user doesn't check that the website he has connected to isn't the one he expected. That's a human problem, not a technical problem, and not one you can solve in software. (3) 'Fingerprinting the Web server' isn't mentioned in your question. (4) Performance is 100% irrelevant if it doesn't work. You can't measure the performance of a non-working solution.

Comment: I'm really sorry for the way i've directed my question, it is ambiguous probably because i am  a beginner. You know when a browser trys to communicate with a server over SSL in the SSL handshake i get a certificate from the server which is vouched by a Certificate Authority. That means for secure communication to exist i solely trust my CA to ensure secure communication. It is a known fact that these CAs can't be trusted, so i need an extra check on the client side to confirm if its the actual certificate and the true identity from the server its coming from. This is what i set out to do

Comment: They've been some solutions to this such as petname and co using browser extensions. Because i want to give my project a kind of novelty and meaning i want to use an Applet instead basically because it can work on different platforms and "they say Applet are faster than add ons which i don't know yet" so that i can do a performance analysis. Please, can you guide me in achieving this??.

Comment: My Applet will operate locally, probably by looking into the browser's certificate store and do this security check with java codes. I just need help on how to go about this. Thanks.